# what can be the regex for string that does not allow to enter only blank space or any other special character?

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I am trying to validate Address field which is marked as Required in my project. But it allows user to enter only blank space and special character in field and proceed further which ideally should not happen.

Below are the regex that I have tried:

```
^[*|\":<>[\\]{}`\\()';@&$]*$

^[0-9]+\s+([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Edit:
Below image shows that it doesn't accepts valid address but allows complete blank spaces

[image]

I want address field to accept alphanumeric field but should not allow complete blank spaces and only special characters.

for example:

**Valid**:

```
RBI Square
123 Mount road
```

**Invalid** :

```
"Complete blank spaces"
.!@#$%^&*()_+|}{[]":';><//., (Completely special characters)
```

Comment: Your second regex won't allow a single space or special character from what I can see.  Can you post the full logic behind what matches and what does not match?

Comment: Can you give examples of what you want and dont want, please

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: I have edited my question @TimBiegeleisen. Please check.

Comment: I have edited my question @Saruman. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this pattern `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]).+`.

With positive lookahead you check if characters, starting from the beginning of a line (anchor `^`) contain at least one upper or lower case letter or digit. If that condition is satisfied, match whole line with `.+` after lookahead.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/AIrSmE/1)

I recommend [this](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#uses) for further reading.

**UPDATE**

This pattern will match additioonaly blank spaces `^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z0-9]| +)).+`.

[Update demo.](https://regex101.com/r/AIrSmE/2)

Comment: I tried ^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]).+ regex and it is working fine with special character validations but doesn't not validate immediately if I enter only spaces although validates the same on form submission.

Comment: @NewbieCoder What do you mean? It doesn't match only spaces, as you wanted.

Comment: Yes. It matches spaces after submitting the form not on focus out.

Comment: No, it won't match white spaces, see demo I posted.

Comment: Oh okay, but I want a one that matches blank spaces as well.

Comment: I think I created a confusion here. What I want is the regex should restrict user from entering all blank spaces and moving ahead in field.

Comment: @NewbieCoder Now you condratict yourself, you said: "Oh okay, but I want a one that matches blank spaces as well" in comments and in question you stated "it allows user to enter only blank space [..] which ideally should not happen." . Make up your mind. You have solution for both.

Comment: @NewbieCoder If answer helped you, you should accept answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: I have already up voted answer as it definitely helped me. Thanks for the help.